# Is it possible to select a div inside another that contains a specific child in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way, in CSS, to select a div inside another that contains a specific child like this:

[image]

I know it can be done using jQuery, but i'm looking for a way to do it ONLY using CSS.

Comment: Why are you posting an image at all? An image of text content should be just text.

Comment: And you want to use an element to select a child of its ancestor, but the two elements are not siblings? That's not possible in CSS.

Comment: What does "Using this div ( a[href*="/u313"] )" mean? That's obviously an a, not a div.

Comment: [Once upon a time, there was a consideration of such a possibility](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#content-selectors).

Comment: @David Thomas: [`:contains()` is for textual content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors), you're probably thinking of jQuery's `:has()`.

Comment: No, I was just wrong about the `:contains ` pseudo-selector. I hadn't realised it was just for textual content. Pity, a CSS implementation of `has ()` would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with plain CSS

You can only make rules where the selectors are parents, whereas your anchor is not a parent of `.content.clearfix`

This can be done using jQuery however. Heres an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/b95TB/

Comment: Ok, I guess it can't be done then, thank you for replying so fast, and posting the image. I guess it can be closed.